# What is the term for a one-level decision tree whereby whichever condition resolves to true, that node wins?

Tags: terminology

Provided I have the following proposal:

> Starting from the top, which ever item resolves to true first, will decide an animal's costume in the party.
>
> 1) If its a Dog, use Green costume.
>
> 2) If its a Cat, use Red costume.
>
> 3) If its a German Shepherd, use Blue costume.

If not already obvious, if the Dog is a German Shepherd, it wears a Green suit not a Blue one.

What do you call this specific kind of Decision Tree whereby its only 1 level.  And what is the shortest way of saying this proposal?

Comment: The general term in the field of expert systems is [forward chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_chaining). However, if you limit it to just one level, wouldn't it just be a *multiple-choice* question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about decision maths terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [**case statement** (see page 18).](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring99/A22.0002.002/lecture_notes/lecture7.pdf)

However, according to your rules, German Shepherd dogs will wear blue, as dogs, and never wear green, as Shepherds. So why is test 3 even there?